# Python conditional exception messages

Tags: python

I'm using Python 2.7 and am new to custom exceptions. I've read up on them as much as I can but haven't found much help for this particular issue.

I am calling an API which returns a status code with most responses. For example, 0 is 'Success', 1 is 'Wrong number of parameters', 2 is 'Missing parameter', etc.

When I get a response, I check the status to make sure I don't continue if something is wrong. I've been raising a generic exception, for example:

```
if response.get('status') != 0:
    print 'Error: Server returned status code %s' % response.get('status')
    raise Exception
```

How can I create a custom exception that looks up what the status code is and returns it as part of the exception's error message? I envision something like:

```
if response.get('status') != 0:
    raise myException(response.get('status'))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you can define a custom exception class by sub-classing `Exception`:

**Example:**

```
class APIError(Exception):
    """An API Error Exception"""

    def __init__(self, status):
        self.status = status

    def __str__(self):
        return "APIError: status={}".format(self.status)


if response.get('status') != 0:
    raise APIError(response.get('status'))
```

By sub-classing the standard `Exception` class of which all default/built-in exceptions inherit from you can also catch your custom exception quite easily:

```
try:
    # ...
except APIError as error:
    # ...
```

See: [User-defined Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions)

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a custom exception is just like declaring a regular class. Do something like this:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

if response.get('status') != 0:
    raise MyException(response.get('status'))
```

So if the result of `response.get('status')` was 1, you would get `MyException: Wrong Number of Parameters`.

Another shorter version can work, but it wouldn't allow you to name the exception yourself.

```
if response.get('status') != 0:
    raise Exception(response.get('status'))
```

Since `Exception` is a builtin Python class, it will raise an error. Again, if `response.get('status')` was 1, you would get `Exception: Wrong Number of Parameters`.

Comment: @JamesMills Edited. Worded that badly. Thanks